# Developer Story - traditional story read only?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, developer-story, traditional-view

The "Traditional View" under "Developer Story" renders a read only view.
Before "Story View" came into play we could edit content in the "Traditional view".

Is there a reason why this is now read-only?